# Adding pictures to .docx files with Apache POI with XWPFDocument

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I've been trying to add .jpg pictures to .docx files with Apache POI. XWPFDocument.addPictureData doesn't seem to work.

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(...);
InputStream pic = new FileInputStream(...);
docx.addPictureData(pic,Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
docx.write(fos);
```

This creates a new, seemingly blank, .docx file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably late for this one but this issue https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49765 describes your problem.

As of poi-3.7 you can also use `XWPFRun.addPicture(InputStream, int, String, int, int)` to add a picture, like so:

```
docx.createParagraph().createRun().addPicture(pic, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "my pic", Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200));
```

I'll update the answer if I figure out what's actually wrong with the `addPicture` method.